# if the program is maximized and I minimize it and then click back to the program it is in windowed mode?

Tags: qt, windows-10, qml, qtquick2

My program is starting **by default in windowed mode**.
My problem is if I **start it** and then **press on maximize**, then **on minimize** and then **click on it in the taskbar**, it is in **windowed mode** and **not maximized**.

To be honest I made that whole new window because I like programs that have a nice clear design. I don't know if you can change the top of a normal Window like the icon of the close button or the color of it.

***main.qml:***

```
    /***********************************************************************************************************/
    /*********************************************** S T A R T *************************************************/
    /***********************************************************************************************************/

    import QtQuick 2.12
    import QtQuick.Window 2.12
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
    import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
    import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0
    import QtQuick.Controls.Imagine 2.3
    import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
    import QtQuick.Dialogs.qml 1.0
    import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
    import QtQuick.Templates 2.5
    import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0


    ApplicationWindow {

    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 900
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Test")
    color: "#2F3136"
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    property int _max: 0
    property int _min: 0
    property int _resizeRightVar: 0
    property int _resizeLeftVar: 0
    property int _resizeTopVar: 0
    property int _resizeBottomVar: 0
    property bool _resizeRight: true
    property bool _resizeLeft: true
    property bool _resizeTop: true
    property bool _resizeBottom: true
    property int _rRCursor: Qt.SizeHorCursor
    property int _rLCursor: Qt.SizeHorCursor
    property int _rTCursor: Qt.SizeVerCursor
    property int _rBCursor: Qt.SizeVerCursor
    property bool _moveWindow: true


    property int previousX
    property int previousY



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// TOP RECTANGLE WITH TITLE, MINIMIZE, MAXIMIZE, CLOSE ///
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
           width: parent.width
           height: 23
           color: "#202225"
           anchors.top: parent.top

           //////////////////////////////////
           /// TITLE IN THE TOP RECTANGLE ///
           //////////////////////////////////
           Text {
               leftPadding: 6
               topPadding: 1
               opacity: 0.75
               text: mainWindow.title
               font.pixelSize: 14
               font.family: "Dodge"
               color: "white"
           }

           ///////////////////////////////////////
           /// MOUSE AREA IN THE TOP RECTANGLE ///
           ///////////////////////////////////////
           MouseArea {
               anchors.fill: parent
               enabled: mainWindow._moveWindow

               onPressed: {
                   previousX = mouseX
                   previousY = mouseY
               }

               onMouseXChanged: {
                   var dx = mouseX - previousX
                   mainWindow.setX(mainWindow.x + dx)
               }

               onMouseYChanged: {
                   var dy = mouseY - previousY
                   mainWindow.setY(mainWindow.y + dy)
               }

               onDoubleClicked: {
                   //mainWindow.visibility = "Maximized"

                   mainWindow._max ++

                   if(mainWindow._max == 1){
                       mainWindow.visibility = "Maximized"
                       //mainWindow.showMaximized()

                       mainWindow._moveWindow = false

                       mainWindow._rRCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
                       mainWindow._rLCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
                       mainWindow._rTCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
                       mainWindow._rBCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor

                       mainWindow._resizeRight = false
                       mainWindow._resizeLeft = false
                       mainWindow._resizeTop = false
                       mainWindow._resizeBottom = false


                   } else if(mainWindow._max == 2){
                       mainWindow.visibility = "Windowed"
                       //mainWindow.showNormal()
                       mainWindow._max = 0

                       mainWindow._moveWindow = true

                       mainWindow._rRCursor = Qt.SizeHorCursor
                       mainWindow._rLCursor = Qt.SizeHorCursor
                       mainWindow._rTCursor = Qt.SizeVerCursor
                       mainWindow._rBCursor = Qt.SizeVerCursor

                       mainWindow._resizeRight = true
                       mainWindow._resizeLeft = true
                       mainWindow._resizeTop = true
                       mainWindow._resizeBottom = true


                   }

               }

           }


           /////////////////////////////////////////
           /// CLOSE BUTTON IN THE TOP RECTANGLE ///
           /////////////////////////////////////////
           Rectangle {
               id: close_window
               width: 27
               height: 22.5
               anchors.top: parent.top
               anchors.topMargin: 0
               anchors.right: parent.right
               anchors.rightMargin: 0
               color: "#202225"

               Image {
                   id: closeImage
                   source: "close_window.png"
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   opacity: 0.6
                   fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
               }

               MouseArea {
                   id: close_windowMouseArea
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   hoverEnabled: true

                   cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor

                   onClicked: {
                       mainWindow.close()
                   }
                   onEntered: {
                       cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
                       close_window.color = "#F04747"
                       closeImage.opacity = 1
                   }
                   onExited: {
                       cursorShape: Qt.ArrowCursor
                       close_window.color = "#202225"
                       closeImage.opacity = 0.6
                   }
               }
           }


           ////////////////////////////////////////////
           /// MAXIMIZE BUTTON IN THE TOP RECTANGLE ///
           ////////////////////////////////////////////
           Rectangle {
               id: maximize_window
               width: 27
               height: 22.5
               anchors.top: parent.top
               anchors.topMargin: 0
               anchors.right: parent.right
               anchors.rightMargin: 29
               color: "#202225"

               Image {
                   id: maximizeImage
                   source: "maximize_window.png"
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   opacity: 0.6
                   fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
               }

               MouseArea {
                   id: maximize_windowMouseArea
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   hoverEnabled: true

                   cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor

                   onClicked: {

                       mainWindow._max ++

                       if(mainWindow._max == 1){
                           mainWindow.visibility = "Maximized"
                           //mainWindow.showMaximized()

                           mainWindow._moveWindow = false

                           mainWindow._rRCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
                           mainWindow._rLCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
                           mainWindow._rTCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
                           mainWindow._rBCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor

                           mainWindow._resizeRight = false
                           mainWindow._resizeLeft = false
                           mainWindow._resizeTop = false
                           mainWindow._resizeBottom = false


                       } else if(mainWindow._max == 2){
                           mainWindow.visibility = "Windowed"
                           //mainWindow.showNormal()
                           mainWindow._max = 0

                           mainWindow._moveWindow = true

                           mainWindow._rRCursor = Qt.SizeHorCursor
                           mainWindow._rLCursor = Qt.SizeHorCursor
                           mainWindow._rTCursor = Qt.SizeVerCursor
                           mainWindow._rBCursor = Qt.SizeVerCursor

                           mainWindow._resizeRight = true
                           mainWindow._resizeLeft = true
                           mainWindow._resizeTop = true
                           mainWindow._resizeBottom = true


                       }

                   }
                   onEntered: {
                       maximize_window.color = "#2B2D30"
                       maximizeImage.opacity = 1
                   }
                   onExited: {
                       maximize_window.color = "#202225"
                       maximizeImage.opacity = 0.6
                   }
               }
           }


           ////////////////////////////////////////////
           /// MINIMIZE BUTTON IN THE TOP RECTANGLE ///
           ////////////////////////////////////////////
           Rectangle {
               id: minimize_window
               width: 27
               height: 22.5
               anchors.top: parent.top
               anchors.topMargin: 0
               anchors.right: parent.right
               anchors.rightMargin: 57
               color: "#202225"

               Image {
                   id: minimizeImage
                   source: "minimize_window.png"
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   opacity: 0.6
                   fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
               }

               MouseArea {
                   id: minimize_windowMouseArea
                   anchors.fill: parent
                   hoverEnabled: true

                   cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor

                   onClicked: {

                       mainWindow._min ++

                       if(mainWindow._min >= 1){
                           mainWindow._min = 0
                           //mainWindow.showMinimized()
                           mainWindow.visibility = "Minimized"

                           //if(mainWindow._max == 1){
                           //    mainWindow.showMaximized()
                           //    mainWindow.visibility = "Maximized"
                           //}
                       }

                   }
                   onEntered: {
                       minimize_window.color = "#2B2D30"
                       minimizeImage.opacity = 1
                   }
                   onExited: {
                       minimize_window.color = "#202225"
                       minimizeImage.opacity = 0.6
                   }
               }
           }
       }



       ///////////////////////////
       /// RIGHT RESIZE WINDOW ///
       ///////////////////////////
       MouseArea {
           id: rightResize
           width: 5
           enabled: mainWindow._resizeRight

           cursorShape: mainWindow._rRCursor

           anchors {
               right: parent.right
               top: parent.top
               bottom: parent.bottom
           }

           onEntered: {
               if(mainWindow._resizeRight == true){
                   mainWindow._rRCursor = Qt.SizeHorCursor
               } else if(mainWindow._resizeRight == false){
                   mainWindow._rRCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
               }
           }

           onPressed: previousX = mouseX

           onMouseXChanged: {
               var dx = mouseX - previousX
               mainWindow.setWidth(parent.width + dx)
           }

       }

       //////////////////////////
       /// LEFT RESIZE WINDOW ///
       //////////////////////////

       MouseArea {
           id: leftResize
           width: 5
           enabled: mainWindow._resizeLeft

           cursorShape: mainWindow._rLCursor

           anchors {
               left: parent.left
               top: parent.top
               bottom: parent.bottom
           }

           onEntered: {
               if(mainWindow._resizeLeft == true){
                   mainWindow._rLCursor = Qt.SizeHorCursor
               } else if(mainWindow._resizeLeft == false){
                   mainWindow._rLCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
               }
           }

           onPressed: previousX = mouseX

           onMouseXChanged: {
               var dx = mouseX - previousX
               mainWindow.setX(mainWindow.x + dx)
               mainWindow.setWidth(mainWindow.width - dx)
           }

       }

       /////////////////////////
       /// TOP RESIZE WINDOW ///
       /////////////////////////
       MouseArea {
           id: topResize
           height: 5
           enabled: mainWindow._resizeTop

           cursorShape: mainWindow._rTCursor

           anchors {
               top: parent.top
               left: parent.left
               right: parent.right
           }

           onEntered: {
               if(mainWindow._resizeTop == true){
                   mainWindow._rTCursor = Qt.SizeVerCursor
               } else if(mainWindow._resizeTop == false){
                   mainWindow._rTCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
               }
           }

           onPressed: previousY = mouseY

           onMouseYChanged: {
               var dy = mouseY - previousY
               mainWindow.setY(mainWindow.y + dy)
               mainWindow.setHeight(mainWindow.height - dy)

           }

       }

       ////////////////////////////
       /// BOTTOM RESIZE WINDOW ///
       ////////////////////////////
       MouseArea {
           id: bottomResize
           height: 5
           enabled: mainWindow._resizeBottom

           cursorShape: mainWindow._rBCursor

           anchors {
               bottom: parent.bottom
               left: parent.left
               right: parent.right
           }

           onEntered: {
               if(mainWindow._resizeBottom == true){
                   mainWindow._rBCursor = Qt.SizeVerCursor
               } else if(mainWindow._resizeBottom == false){
                   mainWindow._rBCursor = Qt.ArrowCursor
               }
           }

           onPressed: previousY = mouseY

           onMouseYChanged: {
               var dy = mouseY - previousY
               //mainWindow.setY(mainWindow.y + dy)
               mainWindow.setHeight(mainWindow.height + dy)

           }

       }


       ////////////////////////////
       /// TEXT INPUT IN MIDDLE ///
       ////////////////////////////
       Rectangle{
           id: textInputBG
       }
}

/***********************************************************************************************************/
/************************************************** E N D **************************************************/
/***********************************************************************************************************/
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you also might want to move the logic that moves the window to C++, moving your window around would otherwise be very jittery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hacky way to solve this:
Add `property int saved_state` to your `ApplicationWindow`

Then add the following code:

```
onVisibilityChanged: {
    if(saved_state === 4 && visibility === 2) {
        showMaximized()
        saved_state = -1
    }
}
```

Then isnide your `MouseArea` `minimize_sindowMouseArea` add the following line:

```
saved_state = mainWindow.visibility //NEW LINE
mainWindow.visibility = "Minimized" //Existing line
```

Explanation: Save the state of your window right before you minimize, then restore it to the `save_state` when restored.
I don't know of any cleaner way, but that should do it :)

Comment: 4 === maximized, 2 === normal (that's what your app is doing when restored it's going back to normal, so you can detect that and maximize it instead)